# How to call various python functions in a Django project from the front-end?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, chatbot, django-channels

I'm working on a chatbot type of web application which I need to build using Django. I have developed a small prediction ML model and have build a small flow for the conversation to take place. The conversation flow contains a class and few functions inside it. The conversation flow module is something like this:

```
class Arbitrary(object):
    def A(self):
       abc = input()
       ## perform some operation ##
       if this:
          a = Arbitrary()
          return a.B(abc)
       else:
          a = Arbitrary()
          return a.C(abc)

    def B(self, abc):
       abc = input()
       ## perform some operation ##
       return 'something'
    def C(self, abc):
       abc = input()
       ## perform some operation ##
       return 'something more'
```

This piece of code works exactly how I want it on the terminal. The issue is now I want to create a web application in Django in such a way that there is a textbox on the webpage with a button. The user types something and with the click of the button, the text entered should be passed to the function A first and then the same function calls (flow of the conversation) must be followed like it happens in the terminal. **The issue I'm facing here is** the `abc = input()` which is there in each of the function which I'm not able to get from the webpage. I'm only able to call a single function by calling it with the input given by the user on the web page.

Do I need to make use of Websockets (Django Channels)? Or is it possible with AJAX calls itself? I've been stuck on this for a while now and couldn't come to any solution. I hope the question is clear to everyone else please let me know if any other details are required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can make it using django add view and template for your form.Otherwise you can add endpoint and call it using ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but how can I call different python functions every time using AJAX? What I have already tried is to call a single python function via AJAX but for the next input from the user, I need it to contact the next functions in the flow, like in the example provided. How do I achieve that? Can you give any example?